# Plotting solution as a function of a specific parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to plot the solutions of the following system as a function of a parameter `\[Gamma]`. The working code is

```
\[Omega] = -2;
Manipulate[
sol = First[
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == \[Omega]*x[t] - \[Gamma]*x[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*y[t], 
 x[t /; t <= 0] == 1, 
 y'[t] == \[Omega]*y[t] - \[Gamma]*y[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*x[t], 
 y[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]];

Plot[Evaluate[Re@{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-100, 100}},
PlotStyle -> {Thick}, Frame -> True], {{\[Gamma], 0.1}, 1, 
10}, {{\[Alpha], 0.1}, 1, 10}]
```

I have tried with `Table` but the output gives errors. I want to plot $x$, $y$ as functions of `[Gamma]`, i.e., `[Gamma]` on the x-axis.

Comment: you say you want gamma on x axis, but your plot command uses `t` for the x axis. but general advice: before throwing everything into Manipulate, first make sure it works outside Manipulate. i.e. see if the plot works, etc.., only then, move things to Manipulate.

Comment: @Nasser, Noted. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[Omega] = -2;
Manipulate[
 X = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[
      t] == \[Omega]*x[t] - \[Gamma]*x[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*y[t], 
    x[0] == 1, 
    y'[t] == \[Omega]*y[t] - \[Gamma]*y[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*x[t], 
    y[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {\[Gamma]}];
 Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[
      t] == \[Omega]*x[t] - \[Gamma]*x[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*y[t], 
    x[0] == 1, 
    y'[t] == \[Omega]*y[t] - \[Gamma]*y[t]^2 - \[Alpha]*x[t], 
    y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {\[Gamma]}];
 Plot[{Re[X[\[Gamma]][t0]], Re[Y[\[Gamma]][t0]]}, {\[Gamma], 1, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Gamma]", ""}], {{t0, 5}, 1, 
  10}, {{\[Alpha], 0.5}, .1, 1}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks. The first manipulator $t0$ is time?

Comment: Yes, t0 is time.